# "Cannot find module './style' or its corresponding type declarations" error, typescript linter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, tslint, css-modules

I'm building a Gatsby project with `css-modules` and `gatsby-config.js`, where I resolve a `.scss` extension.

It builds and it works great BUT my linter doesn't agree with this, firing an error "**Cannot find module './style' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)**" when I try to import styles like that:

[image: ts-error]

No errors if I'm importing from js/ts/jsx/tsx files but when I try to import styles (or images) like modules, without a proper extension, it fires this error.

I already tried to declare extensions as modules inside a "typings" folder in the root of the project, like "declare module "*.scss"", didn't work.

My `gatsby-config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Title from siteMetadata',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
      options: {
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          sourceMap: isDev,
          modules: {
            mode: 'local',
            localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-alias-imports',
      options: {
        alias: {
          '@containers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/containers'),
          '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
          '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages'),
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.css', '.scss'],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@containers/*": ["src/containers/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["src/pages/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

My `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2020: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
    'prettier',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 11,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error'],
    indent: ['error', 2],
    'no-unused-vars': 'warn',
    'import/no-unresolved': 'off',
    'import/extensions': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [
      'error',
      {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I would be grateful for your help. At least, maybe there's some method to turn this ts-rule off?

Answer (score 5):

create a file next-env.d.ts at root and add the below statement to that file

```
 declare module '*.css'
```

**Before adding the above statement**

[image]

**After adding the statement**

[image]

Comment: So what is supper strange is that if I close the next.env.d.ts file then I get the error again. how does that even make sense?

Comment: @loekTheDreamer Did you find a solution to that?

Comment: @Christian not yet,  im using require, it is very annoying.

Comment: @loekTheDreamer make a jsconfig.json. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig make sure the include property points to a directory containing next-env.d.ts (so root, "**/*")

Answer (score 2):

If your directory structure is `src/style/**/*.scss`

change `"baseUrl": "."` to `"baseUrl": "src"` in `tsconfig.json` file.

Or Update `tsconfig.json`

Where the ".scss" type is define.

```json
  "include": [
    "./typings/type.d.ts",
  ],
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didin't help. my directory structure is like `src/components/some-component/style.scss`

Comment: @tjnk24 Try change `import style from './style'` to `import style from './style.scss'`.

Comment: that's the point of the question. I configured gatsby like I don't need to write extensions explicitly, with a "resolve-extensions" array in `gatsby-plugin-alias-imports` options. and it works great. what I want is to get rid of that falsy error.

Comment: @tjnk24 Updated answer, you can try.

Comment: still doesnt work, I already have a folder "typings" with extensions.d.ts, where I declare extension like this:

`declare module '*.scss' {
  const value: Record<string, string>;
  export default value;
}`

This declaration helps to avoid lint errors when I import styles with an extension explicitly written, like `import style from './style.scss';` but not without it.